Is this function positive (semi)-definite?
Let $A$ be a real positive (semi) definite matrix and $$\varphi: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$$ with
$$
\varphi(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^T A  \mathbf x
$$
Is $\varphi$ positive (semi) definite?
For clarification:

A matrix $A$ is positive definite if $\mathbf x^T A  \mathbf x > 0$ for all nonzero vectors $\mathbf x$.
A function $\varphi$ is positive definite if
$$\forall n \in \mathbb N. \; \forall \mathbf x_1, \ldots \mathbf x_n \in \mathbb R^d. \;\forall \alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n \in \mathbb C. \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n\varphi(\mathbf x_i - \mathbf x_j) \alpha_i \bar\alpha_j > 0$$

Given that $\varphi$ is defined in a way that reflects the fact that $A$ is p(s)d I wonder if this makes $\varphi$ also p(s)d.

If $A=0$, then the answer is trivially yes, since $\varphi\equiv 0$. Otherwise there exists some $x_1$ such that $x_1^TAx_1=1$. Let $x_2=0$ and let $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)=(1,-1)$. Then \begin{align*} \sum_{j,k=1}^2\varphi(x_j-x_k)\alpha_j\overline{\alpha}_k & = 0+x_1^TAx_1(1)(-1)+(-x_1)^TA(-x_1)(-1)(1)+0 \\ & = -2. \end{align*}
